# Does Inner RIM matter in fitting a snow chain

Tags: nissan, wheels, snow-chain

I need to buy two snow chains for my car with the size of 225 45R 19 (Nissan Qashghai 2016),

[image]
I have found a snow chain that fits:

225/45-18

225/50-17

225/55-16

So, will this snow chains fit the wheel of Nissan Qashghai, or I shall keep looking for a chain which fits the exact numbers (i.e. 225 45R 19).

Base on this [figure](http://kadawathatyrecentre.com/images/tyre_help.png) and my understanding, it seems the last set of numbers (inner rim) does not seem import, but would like to know the opinion of some experts (thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16 or 17 or 18 is the diameter of the wheel.

As the tire has both inner and outer diameters the same, then for the tire to fit the inner diameter of the wheel has to be the same as the outer diameter. So not sure why your source says inner diameter.

See this for an explanation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_code

Note that if you use a snow chain with too small a diameter, then it can foul the brakes or steering components on the inside of the wheel with serious consequences.

Comment: thanks for the explanation,  "too small a diameter", does it mean one inch, (e.g. 18 vs 19), or it is more than an inch?However, the best case, based on your answer, is 100$ match in numbers, right?

Answer (score 2):

Nissan Qashqai owner's manual suggest you should use the following tire sizes:

[image]

It would be best to use these sizes while searching for the right size of your chains. However it is also possible to use tyre calculator (like [this one](https://tiresize.com/tyre-size-calculator/)) to compare your tire with ones advertised with a chain. Sizes you've listed are  smaller diameter tires than your original one, so chain would be too small.

Comment: The OP **is** using one of the sizes as mention in the chart you show - 3rd one from the top...

Comment: @SolarMike, I don't think OP is using the size you refer to (I see it only provided as an example of tires on the car) to chose the chains as there are three other sizes listed afterwards, all of which are smaller than the original size. It would be best to see one of the sizes from the table within the list of suitable tires for a chain.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment has to do with your answer as well as I have no clue what your answer has to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @Alex, when I search for my tyre, it shows "Alternate Tyre Sizes" as a suggestion, does this mean that if a chain fits "Alternate Tyre Sizes" it also fits mine?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough side wall on the 19 inch I rarely use chain as I have 4 wheel drive and live in So Calif. But chains wrap around and would damage an extreamly low profile tire perhaps you might want to rent a car or take your friends car up to the mountains if that's the reason you need chains. I think the cables will wrap and damage your rims as well.